# Core Data Convenience Fetch Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have managed objects that I access using fetch requests.
Writing the fetch request again and again every single time I want the objects is tedious, so I made myself a convenience method that contains the fetch request.

My object is WeekDay, and to retrieve all WeekDay objects I created the following method in WeekDay class:

```
+ (NSArray *)allWeekDaysWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WeekDay"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"day" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    return [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
}
```

This code works, yet I do feel that something is wrong.
Moving the managedObjectContext as a parameter every single time, although I have only one managedObjectContext is just annoying. I read that Apple recommends View Controllers to pass the managedObjectContext like this, but is this recommendation still applied to non-ViewController classes?

Is there a naming convention for such methods? I just really really smell that this piece of code is tedious every time I use this method.

Comment: How about using a helper class (which has a moc as @property) that does all the CoreData stuff for you: saving, fetching, etc. So you could write a very general fetchrequest where you pass in the entityname, attribute, sorting, etc.

Comment: @Koen First thank you for helping :) What you suggested is actually a pretty good idea. If I take the method above and generalise it, it would be useful for other classes but I think I'd still have to pass the managedObjectContext as a parameter, wouldn't I ? (Because this method is a class method) Again, thanks for helping :)

Comment: No, you wouldn't have to. The helper class has a @property for the context, and you would use `result = [self.context executeFetchRequest: request error: &error]` Also you don't need a class method for this, and make sure you test for the error (don't pass nil).

Comment: @Koen How can I create this method without using class method? I mean, I don't know what the object is, I haven't retrieved it, so how can this method be an instance-method?

Comment: You need to make a complete new NSObject sublass that you call CoreDataHelper or something like that, and make it a @property of your AppDelegate, that's how you access it.

Comment: @Koen Isn't it just simpler to get the managedObjectContext using the appDelegate through UIApplication instead of creating this helper object? is the helper object more efficient?

Comment: If you have only one convenience method, you could stick it in AppDelegate.

Comment: @NoamSolovechick It's the general concept of having a different class that does the saving to separate it from your logic. While it is easier for you to do it right now in AppDelegate, if you ever need to add more convenience methods, then it starts to bloat your appDelegate/code. It's a pretty standard pattern that devs will use with CoreData though. It gets more handy when you start accessing the MOC from multiple threads or even need to change the accessing/saving methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you have developed here is fine.  You should pass in the context so that when you add another context you won't need to refactor.  You can roll these into a helper class if you want but I tend to put them into the data object classes themselves.  It makes it very clear what is happening.